# HTML5 Video changing the source back and forth with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video

Hey guys I'm trying to switch between sources of my HTML5 video, I can make it work so that it switches from A to B but it doesn't wanna change back from B to A.

I tried A lot of different ways of writing it but it doesn't seem to work.
So I hope somebody can help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/p463qvnL/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
      <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .buttons{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999;
        bottom: 0;

      }
      .button {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
        border: 0;
        border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
      }
      .button:focus {
        border: 0;
        border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
        outline:0;

      }
      .twee {
        background-color: green;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
   <body>   
    <div>
     <div class="buttons">
       <button class="button" id="pause"></button>
       <button class="button twee" id="switch"></button>
     </div>
     <video loop autoplay id="video1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <source id="video2" src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
   </div>

  <script>
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
    var myVid = document.getElementById("video2");

    document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener ("click", playPause);
    document.getElementById("switch").addEventListener ("click", switchScreen);


    function playPause(){
      if (myVideo.paused){
           myVideo.play();
         } else {
           myVideo.pause();
          }
         }

     function switchScreen(){
       if (myVid.src = "mov_bbb.mp4"){
           myVid.src = "lal.mp4";
          } else {
             myVid.src = "mov_bbb.mp4";
          }
        myVideo.load();
       }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (myVid.src = "mov_bbb.mp4")
> ```

`=` is an **assignment** not a comparison (like `==` or `===`) so that statement will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

= is an assignement aperator use == or === for comparision

besides, this is more readable:

```
function switchScreen(){
  myVid.src = myVid.src === "mov_bbb.mp4" ? "lal.mp4" : "mov_bbb.mp4";
  myVideo.load();
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I know but if you don't use a single = it doesn't change at all from A to B.

Comment: of course you need the single = to assign the video url, but not in the condition

Comment: That seems odd, on jsfiddle it works but locally it doesn't with the same code :/

Comment: Could it have to do something with that the video's are locally stored?

Comment: maybe but that is a different issue, if you print myVid.src it should be toggling

Comment: Yeah I should delete this then thanks for helping, the problem is that with the URL is changes but if the video's are locally it doesn't. And I need to have everything working locally.

Comment: but still, the = and == thing remains an issue in your code

Comment: Nah I had that as my first version but it didn't work, but when I tried it with a single = it worked half so posted it like this. But now I know the real reason why It didn't work.

Comment: ok look, there is no way ```if (myVid.src = "mov_bbb.mp4")``` works! it always returns true. That's it.